# Search database table by record fields and display record on cxgrid

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, sybase-asa, tcxgrid

What is the best way to allow a user to search for a record in a database table by typing text into a tedit box clicking a button then the results will then display onto a tcxgrid.

I have a tadquery/datasource that is looking at a table which contains various fields. It would be nice if the user was able to search for more than one field in the table.

Thanks.

Comment: You have to accept the multiple field names and values, and use `TDataSet.Locate`. How you design the interface to do so is up to you and your specific requirements.

Comment: I have done the following code but get error message..'variant or safe array index out of bounds'.

Comment: You can't do it that way. You've said there are two columns ("Customer_Code" and "Name"), and so the array has to have two elements (index 0 = Customer_Code and Index 1 = Name). You're only putting one element in the array.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, could you give example. This is what I have so far... **Locate('customer_code;name',(editSearch.Text),[loPartialKey,loCaseInsensitive]);**

Comment: You can use the TcxFiltercontrol or TcxDbFilterControl

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TDataSet.Locate` for this, passing a semicolon delimited list of field names and an array of constant field values to match. Typically, this is easy:

```
DataSet.Locate('Field1;Field2', ['Value1', 'Value2'], [loPartialKey]);
```

However, as you don't know ahead of time how many columns, you'll need to handle the array differently, using `VarArrayCreate` and setting each array value separately.

This example takes the list of fields from `Edit1` (separated by semicolon), the list of values to match from `Edit2` (again, separated by semicolons, with string values surrounded by `'` characters so they're properly included in the array). It splits the content of `Edit1` into an array to find out how many elements, allocates a variant array of the proper size, populates it, and then passes both the field list and the array of values to `TDataSet.Locate`. It was tested with `Edit1.Text := 'Customer_No;Name';` and `Edit2.Text := '1;''Smith''';`.

```
procedure TForm5.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Temp: string;
  Fields: TArray<string>;
  Vals: TArray<string>;
  FieldValues: Variant;
  i: Integer;
begin
  // Grab a copy so we can split it into separate values
  Temp := Edit1.Text;
  Fields := Temp.Split([';']);

  // Create the array of variants to hold the field values    
  FieldValues := VarArrayCreate([0, High(Fields)], VarVariant);

  // Temporary copy to allow splitting into individual values      
  Temp := Edit2.Text;
  Vals := Temp.Split([';']);
  for i := 0 to High(Fields) do
    FieldValues[i] := Vals[i];

  // Use original field list from Edit1 for the Locate operation
  DataSet1.Locate(Edit1.Text, FieldValues, [loCaseInsensitive]);
end;
```

For versions of Delphi prior to the inclusion of `TStringHelper` (such as the XE2 you're using, just add `Types` and `StrUtils` to your uses clause and use `SplitString` and `TStringDynArray` instead:

```
procedure TForm5.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Temp: string;
  Fields: TStringDynArray;
  Vals: TStringDynArray;
  FieldValues: Variant;
  i: Integer;

begin
  Temp := Edit1.Text;
  Fields := SplitString(Temp, ';');

  FieldValues := VarArrayCreate([0, Length(Fields)], VarVariant);
  Temp := Edit2.Text;
  Vals := SplitString(Temp, ';');
  for i := 0 to High(Fields) do
    FieldValues[i] := Vals[i];

  DataSet1.Locate(Temp, FieldValues, [loCaseInsensitive]);
end;
```

Comment: sorry ive only just seen this, you can ignore previous comment from above

Comment: .Split ?...Delphi doesn't recognize that as a property.

Comment: Sorry i should have mentioned that I'm using Delphi XE2

Comment: You actually did (in your tags). Updated to also include a version for earlier versions.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a query for the datasource and in the onclick event of the button, reload the query with a WHERE clause along the lines of

```
Query1.SQL.Add('WHERE Name LIKE :P1 OR Postcode LIKE :P2 OR Town LIKE :P3');
```

and add the parameters

```
Query1.SQL.Parameters.ParamByName('P1').Value := '%' + Edit1.Text + '%';
Query1.SQL.Parameters.ParamByName('P2').Value := '%' + Edit1.Text + '%';
Query1.SQL.Parameters.ParamByName('P3').Value := '%' + Edit1.Text + '%';
```

using '%' to allow searching anywhere in the string as an option.

```
Query1.Open;
```

I've used this technique many times.